# I am trying to print a cart with prices in Django

Tags: python, django

When I pass the context, the other end doesn't seem to be able to use it, to make it simpler and give an example I will try passing all my products and simply make a list of all the product id's, it doesn't work, all I get is a blank page when I visit the page.

**views.py**

```
def cart(request):
items = [1,2,3,4]
template = loader.get_template("Cafe/cart.html")
ip = get_client_ip(request)
order = current_order.objects.order_by('id')
products = product.objects.order_by('id')
context = {
    'order': order,
    'products': products,
    'items': items
}
return HttpResponse(template.render(request))
```

**cart.html**

```
    <head>
{% load static %}
{% load app_filters %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'Cafe/stylesheet.css' %}" />
</head>
<body>
  {% for product in products %}
    <a>{{product.id}}</a>
  {% endfor %}
</body>
```

**models.py**

```
class product(models.Model):
    categories = (
        ('HD', 'Hot Drink'),
        ('CD', 'Cold Drink'),
        ('Br', 'Breakfast'),
        ('Sa', 'Sandwich'),
        ('Ex', 'Extras'),
        ('Sp', 'Specials'),
    )
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=categories, default=categories[0][0])
    price = models.FloatField()
```

I don't see a reason why this should not work as the same concept works on all other pages I have made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rendering your template like this:

```
return HttpResponse(template.render(request))
```

You could do:

```
...
context = {'order': order, 'products': products, 'items':items}
return render(request, "cafe/cart.html", context)
```

Right now your `context` variable isn't being used when rendering anything, so you can't access it in the template. Using `render` like this and supplying a context dictionary will give you access to all of the items within the dict like you'd expect.

Comment: Perfect, just completely missed the context as a parameter! I knew it would be something as small as that!